# Align FrameLayout inside ConstraintLayout to bottom

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-view, android-constraintlayout

I want a layout above recycler view at the bottom of the screen,(like a frame) so that even when that layout is visible I can still scroll recycler view behind it. So I want to align the frame layout at the bottom of the screen and make it visible and invisible as per requirement. Here is my code.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.protossoft.root.aesencryption.MainActivity">



    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </ListView>

  <!--  <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content">-->
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="443dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/deviceNumberImage"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:src="@android:drawable/btn_default" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/deviceNumber"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:text="990000862471854" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
   <!-- </RelativeLayout>-->
```

I don't have too much of idea about constraint layout, but when I am moving the view at the bottom from the editor, it is using property like

```
tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="443dp"
```

I want to achieve the same with some property like align_parentBottom. But none of the properties is available for use. What do I need to do so that the frame layout is visible at the bottom and on the top of recycler view at the same time?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

> I want to achieve the same with some property like align_parentBottom.

You should use `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` attribute.

Here's the setup that you need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">
        ...
    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: works perfectly. Exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot.